# Rails multiple resources in a single API endpoint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I have an API endpoint `/videos/:id/feedback` which needs to return a list of comments (Comment Model) and reviews (Review Model) which are intermixed chronologically.

The API up until this point has been paginating results based on the primary key of a singular resource e.g.:

`/users?after=3&limit=3` => [4, 5, 6]

`/users?after=6&limit=3` => [7, 8, 9]

How can I return both resource types intermixed by `created_at` and be able to paginate those results?

**UPDATE**

I've determined that one option would be to use single table inheritance.

Instead of a separate `comments` and `reviews` table I could have a single `feedback` table with a type column. Both the Comment and Review models would then inherit from a Feedback model.

This would solve both the intermixing and pagination issues. However, reviews and comments only have two or three attributes in common and six or more attributes not in common so I'm hesitant to want to go with STI because it feels like an ugly way to go about it.

I wonder if there might be an alternative / cleaner and more developer friendly way to accomplish this.